# Por qué el cin sólo lee un valor negativo? C++

Tags: c++, poo, input

Lo que pasa es que tengo un objeto al cuál debo asignarle valores negativos a sus atributos, al ingresar el primer valor negativo usando el cin todo bien, pero cuando ingreso otro valor, lo ingresa como un 0, no tengo idea a qué se debe.
Por ejemplo: Si trato de cambiar 3 de las variables (ataque mágico, defensa mágica y ataque físico) por -20,-50,-10. Me deja hacerlo, pero al imprimir los atributos en pantalla serán: Ataque mágico = -20%, Defensa mágica = 0%, Ataque físico = 0%. Lo más raro es que cuando corro el programa con el debugger sí se ejecutan los cambios, pero de no hacerlo, sólo cambia el primero. Necesito inicializar las variables "stat" en 0, ya que si el usuario decide no modificar alguna de estas, entonces se le asigna este valor

```
                    int opcion2;
                    int opcion3;
                    bool quienCambia;
                    int stat1 = 0;
                    int stat2 = 0;
                    int stat3 = 0;
                    int stat4 = 0;
                    int stat5 = 0;
                    do {
                        cout << "   Indique el luchador al que afectará la habilidad: " << endl;
                        cout << "   [1] Aliado              [2] Rival" << endl;
                        cout << "   Opción: ";
                        cin >> opcion2;
                        switch (opcion2) {
                        case 1:
                            quienCambia = false;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            quienCambia = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            cerr << "   Error: Opción inválida." << endl;
                            system("pause");
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (quienCambia != true && quienCambia != false);
                    do {
                        system("cls");
                        cout << "   Seleccione las características que desea aumentar/disminuir" << endl;
                        cout << "   [1] Ataque mágico" << endl;
                        cout << "   [2] Defensa mágica" << endl;
                        cout << "   [3] Ataque físico" << endl;
                        cout << "   [4] Defensa física" << endl;
                        cout << "   [5] Velocidad" << endl;
                        cout << "   [6] Terminar" << endl;
                        cout << "   Opción: ";
                        cin >> opcion3;
                        switch (opcion3) {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "   Indique el porcentaje que desea aumentar/disminuir en el Ataque mágico:";
                            cin >> stat1;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2:
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "   Indique el porcentaje que desea aumentar/disminuir en la Defensa mágica:";
                            cin >> stat2;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3:
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "   Indique el porcentaje que desea aumentar/disminuir en el Ataque físico:";
                            cin >> stat3;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4:
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "   Indique el porcentaje que desea aumentar/disminuir en la Defensa física:";
                            cin >> stat4;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 5:
                        {
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "   Indique el porcentaje que desea aumentar/disminuir en la Velocidad:";
                            cin >> stat5;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 6:
                            break;
                        default:
                            cerr << "   Error: Opción inválida" << endl;
                            system("pause");
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (opcion3 != 6);
                    nuevaHabilidad = new HabEstado(stat1, stat2, stat3, stat3, stat5, quienCambia, naturalezaDeHabilidad, nombreHabilidad, canRondas, precision);
                    this->adminHabilidades->ingresaHabilidad(nuevaHabilidad);
                    cout << "   Habilidad creada correctamente." << endl;
                    system("pause");
```

Comment: Creo que te falta código relevante, no se ve cuando creas el struct en cuestión, después del `do-while` accedes y no se ve cuando lo defines ni cuando lo inicializas. Saludos.

Comment: Esta línea es un sin sentido while (quienCambia != true && quienCambia != false);

Comment: @AntonioS.F. de verdad? Es que como es el usuario el que ingresa true o false, puede que ingrese un 2 por ejemplo
Aunque creo que más bien debería ser `while(opcion2!=0 && opcion2!=1);` no?

Comment: Es que no le veo sentido. Mejor sería una variable del tipo bool ValorValido mientras no sea válido sigue en el bucle de otro modo sale. opcion2 ya contiene el valor de quien es el que está cambiando. La condicional que tu usas no la veo correcta desde mi punto de vista. Para eso sería mejor poner  while (quienCambia == null);